# particle hair comes through mesh even with collision

Tags: particles, hair, collision

I am using blender 3.2.1
I have a small animation of a suzanne's head and a hair strand parented to it.

The hair is particle hair. It was made this way: 1) making a curve circle and a path curve, in object data properties Geometry -> object and selecting the curve circle. 2) converting result of previous step into a mesh 3) deleting some vertices 4) Fibermesh in HairNet. (this tutorial "Hair addon blender (HairNet) Part 2" )

My problem is: when suzanne's head moves slowly (+- 15 frames between each keyframe) hair works fine (hair does not come though head), but when the head moves faster (+- 7 frames between each keyframe) hair starts to come through suzanne's ear.

Could you tell me how to make hair collide with suzanne?

[image]
[image]
[image]

I want the hair strand not to come through Suzanne's ear while Suzanne's head is moving fast.

I have ticked "hair dynamics" box. There tried setting a Collision Collection in hair dynamics, but it did not change anything.

I have set a collision modifier to suzanne's head in physics properties. In "soft body and cloth" section I played with *Damping*, *Thickness* *Outer*, *Inner*, but to no avail.

I am new to blender and I will be greatful for any help

link to the file https://cloud.mail.ru/public/zQk3/AiZjPUZAQ